# How do I generate an HTML table from 2D JavaScript array using a double for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, multidimensional-array

This is a multiplication table.  I just need to figure out how to put each individual number into a different cell in a table. I need the corresponding numbers to line up. I have a div called dTable.

```
function createArray(){
var table=new Array()
    for(var i=0; i<21; i++){
    table[i] = new Array()
}
for(var i=1; i<21; i++){
    for(var j=1; j<21; j++){
        table[i][j]=i*j
        dTable.innerHTML=dTable.innerHTML+table[i][j]+" "
    }
    dTable.innerHTML=dTable.innerHTML+"<br>"
}
```

Comment: Can you post a data sample and what you expect the output to be?

Comment: The first `for` loop is typically for the `tr`, and the inner `for` loop is what gives you the cell `td` values.

Comment: Use. The. Dom. Instead. Of. Innerhtml.